# Saving output of EMACS for Multiple files

Tags: python, emacs

I am using an EMACS package (vax) to calculate some tilings of various regions. At the moment I have a large number of text files and I open each one in EMACS, execute a single command,`<Shift> 3`, record the output to the minibuffer manually, and add eventually sum these output. This is incredibly time consuming, and I keep making errors.

I would really like to automate this process, could anyone give me some advice on how I might write some sort of script that will open each file in a specified directory, record the output of the minibuffer after entering the command `<Shift> 3`, and sum the successive outputs as it proceeds through the directory?

I am not familiar with LISP or EMACS, I've read through the tutorial for the latter. I have a rough working knowledge of how to code in Python, and if there is a way I could execute this all within a python script that would be really helpful.

Comment: What's the output of `f1 k S-3`?

Comment: It's a string, for example: "Region of 2*24 vertices, 1 tilings". I need the integer that preceedes tilings.

Comment: `<Shift> 3` calls some command. What is the name of the command?

Comment: # is a special command in the VAX package, in fact `<Shift>` isn't required.

Comment: Can you just type in `f1 k #`?

Comment: I can just type #, not including f1 k.

Comment: Yes:), but that's not what I'm asking you to do. I want to know that command name, and `f1 k #` should output it so that you can tell it to me.

Comment: I can't see directly what the command name is, the output is just:

`3 runs the command (lambda nil (interactive) (if (equal vax-region
(buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))) nil
(vax-quit) (setq vax-region (buffer-substring-no-properties
(point-min) (point-max)))) (catch (quote chromatic) (catch (quote
singular) (vax-number)))), which is an interactive Lisp function.

It is bound to #, 3, <menu-bar> <compute> #.

(anonymous)

Not documented.

[back]`

Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Read about Emacs keyboard macros. Any time you want to repeat the same thing in multiple places, keyboard macros can enable you to automate it (and without writing a single line of lisp).

Comment: @phils How would one read the output of the minibuffer using a macro ? He says "record the output to the minibuffer manually". That's the only step I can't figure out.

Comment: Ehvince: If that actually meant to *manually type* a copy of what was printed in the echo area, then I would advocate just doing the preceding step in such a way that you can more easily get at the output to copy/kill and yank it. You might also be able to get it from `*Messages*`, but in an automated approach you may have to deal with other unrelated messages appearing, so it's not necessarily the simplest or most-reliable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step instructions of how to run emacs in batch:

1. First you need to get the list of files that you want to operate on.
   `find-name-dired` should be enough for most needs. Open `dired`
   in the base directory of your project and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-name-dired`.
   Accept the default for the base directory, enter for instance `*.py` as wildcard.
2. You now have a buffer with all file names that you're interested in.
   Select them all with <kbd>t</kbd>. You can refine your selection with
   <kbd>m</kbd> and <kbd>DEL</kbd>.
3. Start a shell command with <kbd>!</kbd>. Use this command template as a start:

   ```
    emacs --batch ? --eval "(message \"%s %s\" (buffer-name) (buffer-size))"
   ```
4. Now you have all your output neatly in the shell output buffer.

The code above shows buffer size in characters for each file.
You should replace `(buffer-size)` with your code, i.e.

`(if (equal vax-region (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))) nil (vax-quit) (setq vax-region (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))) (catch (quote chromatic) (catch (quote singular) (vax-number)))`

The whole thing should be on one line.
Alternatively, you can wrap the call to `emacs --batch` with a bash script
and call that instead from `dired`.

### UPD: try to run this code

Instead of `(buffer-size)`, put `(progn (vax-mode) (call-interactively (vax-col vax-number)))`.

### UPD: load vax.el

Use `emacs --batch ? -l ~/path/to/vax.el --eval "(progn (vax-mode) (message \"%s %s\" (buffer-name) (call-interactively (vax-col vax-number))))"`.

Comment: Right, thank you that's really helpful. There's one thing I still don't understand, the command # is part of this VAX major mode, can I still replace `(buffer-size)` if I am not in this mode?

Comment: Just try it. It's quite an obscure piece of software you're using. I was able to find it only by googling
specifically `vax-number`. And it doesn't run on my emacs24.3.

Comment: It works fine for `(buffer-size)` but when I try it out with the vax code I get an error message:
 
`Symbol's value as variable is void: vax-region`

I know it's an obscure bit of software, but do you have an idea as to why this might happen? I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Can you post a minimal `test.vax` on pastebin that runs correctly for you?

Comment: It gives me an error because I don't have maple. Anyway, the updated code should probably work.

Comment: Right, I forgot about needing Maple too. I tried the updated code, it gave me a different error message:

`Symbol's function definition is void: vax-mode`

Comment: No problem. Keep on truckin with Emacs:)